# What is the difference between Uvicorn and Gunicorn+Uvicorn?

Tags: gunicorn, google-cloud-run, fastapi, uvicorn

What is the difference between deploying FastAPI apps dockerized using Uvicorn and [Tiangolo's Gunicorn+Uvicorn](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker)? And why do my results show that I get a better result when deploying only using Uvicorn than Gunicorn+Uvicorn?

When I searched in Tiangolo's documentation, it says:

> You can use Gunicorn to manage Uvicorn and run multiple of these concurrent processes. That way, you get the best of concurrency and parallelism.

From this, can I assume that using this Gunicorn will get a better result?

This is my testing using JMeter. I deployed my script to Google Cloud Run, and this is the result:

Using Python and Uvicorn:

[image]

Using Tiangolo's Gunicorn+Uvicorn:

[image]

This is my Dockerfile for Python (Uvicorn):

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev python3-pip git
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -U setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt --use-feature=2020-resolver
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["python3", "/usr/src/app/main.py"]
```

This is my Dockerfile for Tiangolo's Gunicorn+Uvicorn:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget gcc -y
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

You can see the error from Tiangolo's Gunicorn+Uvicorn. Is it caused by Gunicorn?

Edited.

So, in my case, I using lazy load method to load my Machine Learning model. This is my class to load the model.

```py
class MyModelPrediction:
    # init method or constructor
    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand

    # Sample Method
    def load_model(self):
        pathfile_model = os.path.join("modules", "model/")
        brand = self.brand.lower()
        top5_brand = ["honda", "toyota", "nissan", "suzuki", "daihatsu"]

        if brand not in top5_brand:
            brand = "ex_Top5"
            with open(pathfile_model + f'{brand}_all_in_one.pkl', 'rb') as file:
                brand = joblib.load(file)
        else:
            with open(pathfile_model + f'{brand}_all_in_one.pkl', 'rb') as file:
                brand = joblib.load(file)

        return brand
```

And, this is my endpoint for my API.

```py
@router.post("/predict", response_model=schemas.ResponsePrediction, responses={422: schemas.responses_dict[422], 400: schemas.responses_dict[400], 500: schemas.responses_dict[500]}, tags=["predict"], response_class=ORJSONResponse)
async def detect(
    *,
    # db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db_api),
    car: schemas.Car = Body(...),
    customer_id: str = Body(None, title='Customer unique identifier')
) -> Any:
    """
    Predict price for used vehicle.\n
    """
    global list_detections
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        brand = car.dict()['brand']
        obj = MyModelPrediction(brand)

        top5_brand = ["honda", "toyota", "nissan", "suzuki", "daihatsu"]
        if brand not in top5_brand:
            brand = "non"

        if usedcar.price_engine_4w[brand]:
            pass
        else:
            usedcar.price_engine_4w[brand] = obj.load_model()
            print("Load success")

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(usedcar.price_engine_4w)
        print("ELAPSED MODEL TIME : ", elapsed_time)

        list_detections = await get_data_model(**car.dict())

        if list_detections is None:
            result_data = None
        else:
            result_data = schemas.Prediction(**list_detections)
            result_data = result_data.dict()

    except Exception as e:  # noqa
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=500,
            detail=str(e),
        )
    else:
        if result_data['prediction_price'] == 0:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=400,
                detail="The system cannot process your request",
            )
        else:
            result = {
                'code': 200,
                'message': 'Successfully fetched data',
                'data': result_data
            }

    return schemas.ResponsePrediction(**result)
```

Comment: What is the average/min/max values in your table? Response times..?

Comment: @Gino Yes, it is average/min/max response times that i got

Comment: Can you also post a sample endpoint that you used for testing? I assume your tests is hitting some endpoint many times. Also, might help to understand that Gunicorn is to parallelize your processes, using workers. It is different from concurrency. See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/

Comment: @GinoMempin I've updated my question, so in my endpoint using Async def here. So async def is not suitable for the parallel process?

Comment: @GinoMempin Okay, when I read the documentation, it was explained that if you are using the Machine Learning model, you can use [Concurrency + Parallelism](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#concurrency-parallelism-web-machine-learning), it said to use `async def` and `await`. if we refer to [tiangolo-gunicorn-uvicorn](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#gunicorn) as we explain before, should go well right?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 83):

**[Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html)** is an [application server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) that interacts with your web-application using the [WSGI](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what.html) protocol. This means that Gunicorn can serve applications written in synchronous web-frameworks such as [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (more so for versions released before 2021). Gunicorn takes care of [running multiple instances](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#server-model) of your web application, making sure they are healthy and restart them as needed, distributing incoming requests across those instances and communicate with the web server. In addition to that, Gunicorn is pretty darn fast about it. A lot of effort has gone into optimizing it.
Gunicorn itself is not compatible with FastAPI because FastAPI uses the fresh [ASGI](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) standard.

**[Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/)** is an application server that supports the [ASGI](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) protocol. It also has an option to start and run several worker processes.
Nevertheless, Uvicorn's capabilities for handling worker processes are more limited than Gunicorn's.

Uvicorn has a [Gunicorn-compatible worker class](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-with-gunicorn).
This will allow you to run asgi-app in Gunicorn! So, if you want to have a good process manager at that level (at the Python level), you can use Gunicorn as the process manager of your asgi-app!

If you have a cluster of machines with [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or another similar complex system to manage distributed containers on multiple machines, then you will probably want to handle replication at the cluster level instead of using a process manager (like Gunicorn with workers) in each container.
One of those distributed container management systems like Kubernetes normally has some integrated way of handling replication of containers while still supporting load balancing for the incoming requests. All at the cluster level.
In those cases, you would probably want to build a Docker image from scratch, installing your dependencies, and running a single Uvicorn process instead of running something like Gunicorn with Uvicorn workers.

Comment: And the issue of ASGI support in gunicorn remains open for 6 years now ([here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1380) it is should anyone wish to contribute:)

Comment: Please note however that k8s pods are not really practical substitutes for gunicorn workers - to name one problem: the limits on the number of pods that a node can handle are much lower (250-1000) than the number of processes per user (up to 4.2 million).

Comment: @mirekphd And gunicorn is not alone. In 2023, there are still blocking calls in the standard library with no `async` alternatives. I guess this says more about the `async` design itself than about tools like gunicorn.

Comment: @mirekphd Your example was right. But I think it doesn't take too many meanings. Fristly we won't use so many processes that it will cause trashing. Secondly we cloud have many nodes for a webserver deployment, so we can reach 1 million processes finally.